# Bittorrent surveillance/monitoring

Tags: untagged

Is there any tool to sniff bittorrent traffic and reassemble data about the torrent? Im looking for file names, peers, tracker address, local IP, etc. This is purely for academic interest in which all parties would be willing participants. I also am assuming that the torrent connections are unencrypted.

Comment: depends on what kind of information you would want to reassemble and where in the network you would want to install it?

Comment: Id be most interested in the file names of any information about the files being transfered. Since this is in a test environment assume that I'm a peer on the same subnet so I can see all the packets the client would see.

Comment: answer updated - file names are only stored in the original torrent file so you can't reconcile traffic to files until you have the torrent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Capsa Network Analyzer](http://www.colasoft.com/download/products/download_capsa.php) can group connections by protocol (including BitTorrent) and provides a wealth of information including throughput, a connection matrix (for remote/local network/peer mapping) and other expected packet sniffing capabilities. There's a tutorial [here](http://www.colasoft.com/capsa/how-to-track-bittorrent-user-in-network-with-colasoft-packet-sniffer.php).

To identify what file names are in the torrents I'd recommend capturing any requests to known trackers and examining `.torrent` files - I don't know of an automated tool for this. Once the torrent has been parsed by the client it requests chunks rather than files, so sniffing BitTorrent traffic without knowing which torrent it's from may be fruitless. There's a list of [950+ trackers here](http://filesharefreak.com/trackers-list/) that you can cross reference against requests.

If you are looking to filter requests or are interesting in packet-shaping [L7-filter](http://l7-filter.sourceforge.net/) is an application layer "deep packet inspection" filter for a few different P2P protocols.

Here's [a good white paper on BitTorrent](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/features/white_paper_how_bittorrent_works).

---

*Capsa's connection matrix*
[image: Capsa's connection matrix]